# How do I alias a url path in ASP.NET WebApp

Tags: asp.net

I'm trying to set aliases for the URL's in my personal website as follows:

http://chepetico.info/joseph_anthony_king/static_pages/home.aspx

to: http://chepetico.info/home.html

http://chepetico.info/joseph_anthony_king/static_pages/resume.aspx

to: http://chepetico.info/resume.html:

http://chepetico.info/joseph_anthony_king/static_pages/downloads.aspx

to: http://chepetico.info/downloads.html

I've tried using URL Rewrite in IIS 7 Manager and updating the web config file but nothing is working.  Does anyone know how I can set up aliases as follows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

URL Rewrite should give you the mapping you are after:

```
<rule name="Shorten URL" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="^joseph_anthony_king/static_pages/(.*)$" />
    <action type="Rewrite" url="{R:1}" />
</rule>
```

However, the re-written URL must point to a valid document. I suspect that's what's not working for you.

To do an alias, you can set up a [virtual directory](http://www.iis.net/configreference/system.applicationhost/sites/site/application/virtualdirectory) in IIS. The problem is that you need a URL segment to act as the alias. If you set up a virtual directory "test" that points to "[path to website base]/joseph_anthony_king/static_pages/", you could use this url: http://chepetico.info/test/downloads.html

I don't know how to get exactly what you want, but maybe that leads you in the right direction.

Comment: Thanks for your help but the url rewriter wasn't working.   In the web config file rewrite has a squiggly blue line.  I ended up placing the aspx files in the app home directory.  Thanks for responding!